# Error when signing out in android and ios using expo react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

Having this App.js (omiting imports):

```
const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer })

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const App = ({ title }) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const openDrawer = () => {
    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        setLoggedIn(false)
        setLoaded(true)
      } else {
        setLoggedIn(user.emailVerified)
        setLoaded(true)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  if (!loaded) {
    return <Loader loading={loaded} />
  }

  return !loggedIn ? (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Register"
        component={RegisterScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ForgotPassword"
        component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      useLegacyImplementation
      drawerContent={props => <LogOut {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Main"
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => null,
        headerRight: ({ color, size = 26 }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="account"
            color={color}
            style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            size={size}
            onPress={() => openDrawer()}
          />
        ),
        drawerPosition: "right",
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{
          title: title,
          drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Califications"
        component={CalificationsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: ({ color, size = 26 }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="arrow-left"
              color={color}
              style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}
              size={size}
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            />
          ),
          title: "Calificaciones",
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="ChangePassword"
        component={ChangePassword}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: ({ color, size = 26 }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="arrow-left"
              color={color}
              style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}
              size={size}
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            />
          ),
          title: "Cambiar contraseña",
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: state.navigationState.title,
})

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <ConnectedApp />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}
export default Root
```

Being this my Main.js

```
const Main = ({ fetchUser, saveTabTitle }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser()
  }, [])

  const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()

  const handleTabPress = title => {
    saveTabTitle(title)
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Course"
      labeled={false}
      activeColor="#f0edf6"
      inactiveColor="#3e2465"
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Course"
        component={CoursesScreen}
        listeners={{
          tabPress: () => {
            handleTabPress("Cursos")
          },
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size = 26 }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="school" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Calendar"
        component={CalendarScreen}
        listeners={{
          tabPress: () => {
            handleTabPress("Calendario")
          },
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size = 26 }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ fetchUser, saveTabTitle }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

When an user first enter the app everything works as expected and after login Main is render. But when the user try to sign out in the web it works fine but on ios and android I am getting this error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in BottomNavigation
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(BottomNavigation))
    in withTheme(BottomNavigation) (created by MaterialBottomTabViewInner)
    in MaterialBottomTabViewInner (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
    in MaterialBottomTabView (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
    in MaterialBottomTabNavigator (created by Main)
    in Main (created by Connect(Main))    
    in Connect(Main) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by DrawerView)  
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)       
    in Background (created by Screen)     
    in Screen (created by DrawerView)     
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)      
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)       
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)  
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)    
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)    
    in MaybeScreen (created by DrawerView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by DrawerView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DrawerView)       
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by DrawerView)    
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by DrawerViewBase)
    in DrawerViewBase (created by DrawerView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by DrawerView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in DrawerNavigator (created by App)   
    in App (created by Connect(App))      
    in Connect(App) (created by Root)     
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Root)
    in Provider (created by Root)
    in Root (created by withDevTools(Root))
    in withDevTools(Root)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)     
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)     
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

I try by the onAuthStateChanged function of firebase get when a user is log in or not and using the useEffect hook get when it changes. This works fine as I found that it is correctly executed and the state variable loggedIn is well set.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript engine is different in web and native. For that reason some functions exists on web but dont in native, like atob() and btoa(). Sounds like that kind of problem

Comment: But after checking again my code I don't think I am using a javascript function like you mentioned. I think the problem may be related to react-navigation but I still haven't found why.  When the user logged in everything works but when it sign out the error happens and if you reload the app the user was correctly sign out.